# How can you prove Nakayama's lemma over nonunital rings using the unitization?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, finitely-generated, rngs

For a nonunital commutative ring $A$, an $A$-module $M$ is called *finitely generated* over $A$ if there is a finite set of elements $x_1,...,x_n\in M$ such that every element of $M$ is of the form $a_1x_1+...+a_nx_n$ for some $a_1,...,a_n\in A$. Under this definition, notice that the ring $A$ may not be finitely generated over itself, for example $A=2\Bbb Z$.

Now let us consider a equivalent form of Nakayama's Lemma below:

> For a nonunital commutative ring $A$ and a finitely generated module $M$ over $A$, there is an element $a\in A$ such that $am=m$ for all $M$.

The proof goes as usual: Write the generator $x_i=a_{i,1}x_1+...+a_{i,n}x_n$ and notice the determinant of the matrix $\phi=\det(a_{i,j}-\delta_{i,j}\Bbb{1}_M)$ vanishes on every element of $M$ while $\phi$ is of the form $\Bbb{1}_M+k\Bbb{1}_M$ for some $k\in A$(just expand out the $\det$.)

To obtain the usual version of Nakayama's lemma, simply replace $A$ by an ideal $\mathfrak a$ in a commutative unital ring with $\mathfrak aM=M$.

**I am requesting another proof of this fact** using unitalization, as I was told the category of all $A$-modules is indeed isomorphic to the category of all $U(A)$-modules, where $U(A)$ is the unitalization of $A$. I really cannot come up with another categorical proof of the nonunital version of Nakayama's Lemma, although this "nonunital" version involves less restriction while seems indeed fundamental in its form. I will be appreciated if another angle is possible to attack this result.

Answer (score 1):

> To obtain the usual version of Nakayama's lemma, simply replace $A$ by an ideal $\mathfrak a$ in a commutative unital ring with $\mathfrak aM=M$.

You can just reverse this argument.  $A$ is an ideal in its unitization $U(A)$, and considering $M$ as a $U(A)$-module, it satisfies $AM=M$.  So, the usual version of Nakayama's lemma gives an element $a\in A$ such that $am=m$ for all $m\in M$.

Comment: I am sorry if I am not making the question clear, but I am looking for a different way to prove the “nonunital” version without the help of any equivalent forms of Nakayama’s Lemma—that otherwise sure wouldn’t be a problem. I wouldn’t consider the unital form of Nakayama’s Lemma to be fundamental, since it reveals no clue why there is an “identity-like” element in a nonunital ring acting on a module if we impose the “finitely generated condition”.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to say, but I'm about 98% sure that my answer is exactly what the person who told you about using the unitization was talking about.

Comment: yes it is possible he means it that way...so let me formulate the question more clearly in this comment first. I consider the existence of “identity acting element” fundamental, which means I will naturally consider the converse statement of the nonunital form of Nakayama’s Lemma: If a module over the ring satisfies the condition must it be finitely generated? If not how should we characterize this property? I was looking for a much more insightful proof, just like how you regard Yoneda’s Lemma as a generalization of Cayley’s theorem, etc.

Comment: "If a module over the ring satisfies the condition must it be finitely generated?" No, obviously not; for instance, given any such module $M$, any direct sum of copies of $M$ has the same property.  I think you are overthinking this and there is not any special insight to be had here; this nonunital version of Nakayama's lemma is so obviously equivalent to the usual unital version that there is no insight you can gain from one that you don't gain from the other.